# Rigid body - objects randomly snapping together

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, snapping, rigidbody

I've tried playing around with substeps and solver iterations, and the collision shape + margin.
Nothing helped yet.
The size of the objects are 0.08 x 0.01m

[image: Rigid body bug]

Comment: have you applied the scales of your objects?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes I have.  My guess is that it might have to do something with the precision, because the items are quite small.

Comment: maybe share your file, it will help someone to find? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, here is the .blend file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/856a4a2ae6de48a38e9e31707a592294

Comment: if you switch from Shape > Mesh to Convex Hull it seems to work better, select one, switch it, then select all the other ones, make the changed one the active one, then Object > Rigid Body > Copy From Active

Comment: Thanks, you're right but I would swear that I've tried it earlier and it generated weird motions too.  (Maybe I forgot to apply it to all the components... )
-I've tried to add more animated passive objects and the particles started to slide across the floor. :/  

Anyway I'm a bit courious why it's not working with mesh.

Comment: Technically I couldn't say, maybe it's harder to calculate properly if it is set to Mesh?

Comment: oh also maybe try to flip the normals? Well actually Convex Hull seems like the way to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select one of your tokens, switch from *Shape > Mesh* to *Convex Hull*, then select all the other ones and *Object > Rigid Body > Copy From Active*. *Convex Hull* seems to work more correctly.